# Padawan rank in the Clone Wars

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I was just wondering what level of authority a padawan would have in the clone wars. Who they would out rank?

Comment: Padawans were "commanders", Knights and Masters were "Generals".

Comment: Related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77398/star-wars-clone-wars-military-ranks?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Commander) and [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Army_of_the_Republic/Legends). Padawans are Jedi Commanders leading regiments of about 2-3k men. Tough luck fighting under a kid huh?

Comment: Yeh that would suck